# What is the correct way of extracting hypernyms from words with wordnet library?

Tags: python, wordnet

I am trying to extract hypernyms with the [wordnet](https://wn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library. However, it is not clear to me how to given a word get the shortest path list of syntnets in order to get its hypernyms. So far I tried this with the help of the documentation:

In:

```
import wn, wn.taxonomy

lemas_list = []
dog = wn.synsets('katze', pos='n', lang='de')[0]

for path in wn.taxonomy.hypernym_paths(dog):
    for i, ss in enumerate(path):
        ss.lemmas()
    lemas_list.append(ss.lemmas())
lemas_list
```

However, here I think the first list its wrong `['Tiger', 'Panthera tigris']` as it is not very related to the word `katze`. Any idea about how to get only the related hypernims?

Out:

```
[['Tiger', 'Panthera tigris'], ['Katze', 'Felidae']]
```